# Running a JUnit test case concurrently

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I followed *[Concurrent JUnit tests with RunnerScheduler](http://blog.mycila.com/2010/05/concurrent-junit-tests-with.html)*. It says I need to use the Java code in [ConcurrentJunitRunner.java](http://mycila.googlecode.com/svn/sandbox/src/main/java/com/mycila/sandbox/junit/runner/ConcurrentJunitRunner.java).

But then part of the code in `ConcurrentJunitRunner.java`

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
                    klass.isAnnotationPresent(Concurrent.class) ?
                            klass.getAnnotation(Concurrent.class).threads() :
                            (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 1.5),
                    new NamedThreadFactory(klass.getSimpleName()));
```

generates the error

> The method isAnnotationPresent(Class) in the type Class is not applicable for the arguments (Class)"

What should I do to remove the error?

Comment: What is Concurrent.class? Is it an [Annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure, that Concurrent.class is [this annotation class](https://mycila.googlecode.com/svn/sandbox/src/main/java/com/mycila/sandbox/junit/runner/Concurrent.java) from the library you are using.

> ```
> @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
> @Target({ElementType.TYPE})
> public @interface Concurrent {
>     int threads() default 5;
> }
> ```

It seems to me, that you have something different.

Comment: concurrent.class was missing , thank q that fixed the problem...